# Kotlin DSL by default for new Android projects?

Tags: android, kotlin, groovy, dsl

When I create new Android projects, gradle files use Groovy DSL by default. It's a pain having to migrate them to Kotlin DSL. Am I missing a setting to support Kotlin DSL by default?

Answer (score 4):

As of Android Studio version 2021.2.1.16, it does not have an option to create project with Kotlin DSL on start. But intellij has this feature(option for selecting groovy or kotlin for gradle build scripts) for long time.
I have raised a ticket [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243973420).

Comment: It looks like this is still open as the duplicate ticket is referenced here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122167538

Answer (score 0):

The Kotlin DSL default support by IDE is expected from Android Studio Giraffe:

> Note: Kotlin is the default language for build configuration starting with Android Studio Giraffe. If you're using AGP 8.1 and the Kotlin DSL for build configuration, you should use Gradle 8.1 for the best experience.

[Official docs](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-kotlin-dsl)

[At this moment it has RC1 status: Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 RC 1 June 22, 2023](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)